# Golang: Why does the compress/gzip Read function not read file contents?

Tags: file-io, go, gzip

I made a text file, that I then compressed with `gzip`. I then run the following `go` program to read the contents of that compressed file.

```
package main

import (
    "compress/gzip"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    handle, err := os.Open("zipfile.gz")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("[ERROR] File Open:", err)
    }
    defer handle.Close()

    zipReader, err := gzip.NewReader(handle)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("[ERROR] New gzip reader:", err)
    }
    defer zipReader.Close()

    var fileContents []byte
    bytesRead, err := zipReader.Read(fileContents)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("[ERROR] Reading gzip file:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("[INFO] Number of bytes read from the file:", bytesRead)
    fmt.Printf("[INFO] Uncompressed contents: '%s'\n", fileContents)
}
```

The response that I get is the following:

```
$ go run zipRead.go
[INFO] Number of bytes read from the file: 0
[INFO] Uncompressed contents: ''
```

Why am I not getting any contents from the file?

I have created zip files on both OS X and Ubuntu. I have build this `go` program on both OS X and Ubuntu with the same result.

Comment: In addition to what [@JimB says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32018378/55504),  you're mis-using `Read`. You need to pass it an allocated slice you want it to put bytes into, you pass a nil slice (`len(fileContents)` == 0 so you're asking for zero bytes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`io.Reader.Read`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) will only read up to `len(b)` bytes. Since your `fileContents` is nil, its length is 0. Allocate some space for it to read into:

```
fileContents := make([]byte, 1024) // Read by 1 KiB.
bytesRead, err := zipReader.Read(fileContents)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("[ERROR] Reading gzip file:", err)
}
fileContents = fileContents[:bytesRead]
```

If you want to read the whole file, you'll have to either use `Read` several times, or use things like [`ioutil.ReadAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) (which may be bad for big files).

Comment: It's also important to note that `Read` can return after reading fewer bytes. If you need to read the fully byte slice passed in use [`io.ReadFull`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull); if you want the full contents use [`ioutil.ReadAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) (but avoid that unless you really need to pre-read the entire contents).

Comment: I did end up using `ioutil.ReadAll`. But I was still curious about why the gzip `Read` was not working. This helps me understand. It would be helpful if this was mentioned on the [doc page](http://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/#Reader.Read). But I suppose it would be assumed knowledge if I had a better understanding of `io.Reader`.